# LINQ get global index

Tags: c#, linq

I have structure:

`List<List<x>> structure = new { {x,x}, {x,x,x,x}, {x,x,x}}`

How can project it to following sequence using linq?

`{1,1},{2,1},{3,2},{4,2},{5,2},{6,2},{7,3},{8,3},{9,3}`

So the first property of resulting element must represent *global index* of base element and the second one must represent *index of group* for which that element belongs to.

Example: 2nd element of 3rd group will be projected to {8,3}:

8 - global index of base element

3 - index of group base element belongs to.

Comment: Provide an example please, it is not very clear what are you expecting in this case

Comment: I think I get it. You want a list of all index pairs ordered accordingly.. Right?

Comment: I've edited a question a little bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by using the versions of `Select` and `SelectMany` that include the index.

```
IList<IList<int>> structure = new[] 
{ 
    new[] { 1, 1 }, 
    new[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
    new[] { 1, 1, 1 } 
};

var result = structure.SelectMany((l, i) => l.Select(v => i))
    .Select((i, j) => new[] {j + 1, i + 1});

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result.Select(l => "{" + string.Join(",", l) + "}")));
```

Outputs

> {1,1},{2,1},{3,2},{4,2},{5,2},{6,2},{7,3},{8,3},{9,3}

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yeah, fixed.